# Android : MapView in a CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-mapview, mapfragment, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm currently trying to put a `Map View` (or a fragment containing the map)inside a `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. I would want to have the parallax effect on it when the `RecyclerView` scrolls. Unfortunately, it isn't showing up at all! Not even the grey grid! The collapsing animation is working though. I've search everywhere, but all I was able to find is about `ImageView` and no other component. So here are my questions :

1. Is it even possible to put anything else than an `ImageView` in a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` ? (The documentation is talking about child views so I thought it was possible)
2. If so, is a fragment allowed as well?
3. Then what am I doing wrong??

> Here is my xml :

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/main_activity_toolbar"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
                android:id="@+id/main_activity_mapview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:apiKey="AIzaSyA-kEuKT39QK8eG7iYWriFgsvkrZZz6zNo"
                android:clickable="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/main_rv_list_places"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

> And the part where I get the map back. `onMapReady` is never
>   triggered.

```
    if (mMap == null) {

        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                mMap = googleMap;
                MapsInitializer.initialize(MainActivity.this);
                //...
                // other stuff here
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: Are you correctly initializing the map (i.e., calling onCreate(), onResume(), onPause() at the same points in the activity)?

Comment: Did you try to use a fragment instead of `MapView` ?

Comment: @m vai Ok... I feel stupid... I didn't call those functions and now that i do it's working great ! Thank you very much :)

Comment: i am working with fragment instead of mapview...the map is scrolling but when i scroll black background remain...i dont knw why? can you help me?

Comment: Hi. I tried to use a fragment and never managed to make it work. Why don't you use a MapView ? It works fine and doesn't change much about how to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
You can use MapView also to display google map.
```

Within Coordinator layout we can use collapsing toolbar with mapview . Its working fine.

Need to mention google map key correctly.

activity_main.xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar_lay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:titleEnabled="false"
            app:statusBarScrim="@null"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
                <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
                    android:id="@+id/map_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="300dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/main_lay"
                    android:apiKey="@string/google_maps_key"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:enabled="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/post_rcycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

MainActivity.Java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener, GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback  {
    private MapView mapView;
    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map_view);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mapView.getMapAsync(this);

}
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mGoogleMap = googleMap;
    mapView.getMapAsync(this);
}
}
```

Comment: `mapView.getMapAsync(this)` line inside will call `onMapReady` so your code will be an endless loop.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me

Use a Fragment instead of MapView

```
 <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                  android:id="@+id/map"
                  android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  tools:context="com.example.axel.googlemapsdemo.MapsActivity"/>
```

Activity

```
    public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

        private GoogleMap mMap;
        RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
        TestAdapter adapter;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
            // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
            setUpRecyclerView();
        }


        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            mMap = googleMap;
   `        // Do stuff
        }
}
```

API Key is in google_maps_api.xml.

My Parent Layout is CoordinatorLayout (I assume is yours as well but it doesn't appear on the question)

**Notice that with this approach CollapsingToolbarLayout scroll overcast Map scroll**

Solution:

```
AppBarLayout mAppBarLayout = (AppBarLayout)findViewById(R.id.appBarLayout);
        CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) mAppBarLayout.getLayoutParams();
        AppBarLayout.Behavior behavior = new AppBarLayout.Behavior();
        behavior.setDragCallback(new AppBarLayout.Behavior.DragCallback() {
            @Override
            public boolean canDrag(AppBarLayout appBarLayout) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        params.setBehavior(behavior);
```

That problem is address here [How to use map fragment correctly in Collapsingtoolbarlayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33430751/how-to-use-map-fragment-correctly-in-collapsingtoolbarlayout)

***NOTE: maybe a Bottom Sheet fits your needs best***

some examples:
http://www.truiton.com/2016/07/android-bottom-sheet-example/
https://github.com/miguelhincapie/CustomBottomSheetBehavior